# how to optimize SQL sub queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This my scenario I tried to search a record in the SQL table using the name. So, I tried to create a subquery and I used like operator also in Postgres. SQL query It's working fine. but it's taking so much time.  So, I checked why it's taking so much time. the reason is the subquery. In the subquery it hitting all the records in the table. How to optimize subquery.

**SQL QUery**

```
SELECT
id, latitude,longitude,first_name,last_name,
contact_company_id,address,address2,city,state_id,    zip,country_id,default_phone_id,last_contacted,image,contact_type_id
FROM contact
WHERE company_id = 001
AND contact_company_id IN (select id from contactcompany where lower( name ) ~*'jack')
```

So, I tried to run this query it's taking 2 seconds and it hit all records in the contact company table that only It's takes time.
How to optimize subquery using SQL?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using (which I would guess is Postgres based on the syntax, so I left that).

Comment: Consider joining instead of using a subquery, then be aware that using `lower(name)` will make any index on `name` useless.

Comment: Your pattern matching disallows using an index, how big is the `contactcompany` table? And `lower( name )` is useless as `~*'jack'` already applies case-insensitiv comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by writing the query using `exists`.  Then, `company_id` is either a string or a number.  Let met guess that it is a string, because the constant is represented with leading zeros.  If so, use single quotes:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contact c
WHERE company_id = '001' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM contactcompany cc
              WHERE cc.name ~* 'jack' AND
                    cc.id = c.contact_company_id
             );
```

Then an index on `contact(compnay_id, contact_company_id)` makes sense.  And for the subquery, `contactcompany(id, name)`.

There may be other alternatives for writing the query, but your question has not provided much information on table sizes, current performance, or the data types.

Comment: Can you please explain why use select 1

Comment: @HariprasathVengatachalam . . . It is easy to type.  The subquery needs to return *something* in most databases (Postgres is an exception), so I always put `1` there.  An empty `select` just looks wrong, even in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Please try a sub query as a inner join with a main table, both query give same result.

Example here :

```
SELECT  contact.id, 
        contact.latitude,
        contact.longitude,
        contact.first_name,
        contact.last_name,
        contact.contact_company_id,
        contact.address,
        contact.address2,
        contact.city,
        contact.state_id,    
        contact.zip,
        contact.country_id,
        contact.default_phone_id,
        contact.last_contacted,
        contact.image,
        contact.contact_type_id
FROM contact As contact
Inner Join contactcompany As contactcompany On contactcompany.id = contact_company_id
WHERE company_id = 001
AND  lower( name ) ~*'jack'
```